# There vs It: 1) <There is> <It is> likely to be heavy snowfall; 2) <There are> <It is> bound to be changes when the new system is introduced

Tags: difference, adjectives, existentials, dummy-pronouns, extraposition

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/likely_1):
**(1a)** ***There** is likely to be heavy snowfall*.
my variant:
**(1b)** ***It** is likely to be heavy snowfall*.

What is the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bound_1):
**(2a)** ***There** are bound to be changes when the new system is introduced*.
my variant:
**(2b)** ***It** is bound to be changes when the new system is introduced*.

What is the difference between (2a) and (2b)?

---

The construction "there is/are + adjective + to be + noun phrase" in the a-variants is somewhat odd to me because I don't understand what meaning the existential "there" has when it is used with adjectives.

The b-variants with "it" are understandable to me because they represent typical examples of extraposition.

The b-variants I suggested are for subsidiary function: it seems to me comparing the a-variants with b-ones will help me to better understand the a-variants themselves.

Comment: Your variant 1b is just less common. But it's [usually just *heavy **snow***, not ***snowfall***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+heavy+snowfall%2Cwas+heavy+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) (and that's [especially true for Brits).](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+heavy+snowfall%2Cwas+heavy+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=20) Compare ***It is** likely to **rain / snow*** (*verbs* likely to happen) and ***There is** likely to be heavy **rain / snow*** (*nouns* likely to exist). And 2b is just weird!

Comment: ...in short, I think the difference is you're mixing up two completely different constructions. It's just about possible to say *It'll be heavy snow when we get there*, but normally that would only happen when ***it = "the weather"*** was already firmly established as contextually relevant. By default, the two constructions are ***There is** likely **to be [noun]*** and ***It is** likely to **verb].***

Comment: **1b)** I can just about manage: *It is bound to be heavy snowfall, not light rain that greets us*. **2b)** My mental auto-fill wants to make changes singular (i.e., to be a major change when…). Best I can do is: *It is bound to be changes in the system that will cause the most chaos when the new system is introduced.*